# Perl version 5.14.1 released before the version 5.12.4?

Tags: perl, version

> perl-5.12.4 release date 20 Jun 2011
>
> perl-5.14.1 release date 17 Jun 2011
>
> Source: [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~lbrocard/perl-5.12.4/)

I didn't get this. Version 5.14.1 released before the version 5.12.4?

Explain it to me please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

perl-5.12.4 is a maintenance version of the 5.12 line, it's only 200 lines of changes (see http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.12.4/pod/perl5124delta.pod), just a couple of bug fixes, and making sure that 5.12 can work on Ubuntu for example.

5.14.1 is the latest version in the 5.14 line. It's modern, it's shiny, this is the one you want!

Answer (score 7):

This is not the first time there has been maintenance releases after a new version has been released

- 5.6.2 came after 5.8
- 5.8.9 came after 5.10
- 5.12.4 came after 5.14

When the developers of Perl are working on one version (currently 5.16), they still maintain the previous two versions (currently 5.12 and 5.14).

The changes that go into maintenance releases are very limited, though. No new features are added, for starters. Primarily, the updates will only include:

- Security fixes.
- Regression fixes. (e.g. something worked in 5.10, but didn't in 5.12.3 could be fixed in 5.12.4)
- Build fixes. (e.g. Making it so 5.12 compiles with new or different compilers)

That means 5.12.4 will not have the new features that were added to 5.14.0, and it won't have most bug fixes either. The point is to make it as safe as possible to get critical fixes.

Answer (score 3):

It's like service packs: Maintenance release 4 of Perl language version 5.12 came out after release 1 of language level 5.14. Move on, citizen, nothing to see here.

Comment: It may even be so that the maintainers want to field-test a bug fix in a later version (like 5.14) before backporting it to an earlier one (like 5.12) where stability is more important. So they keep the 5.12.4 release back until they see that 5.14.1 flies.

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of perl get maintenance releases.  For instance, Perl 1.0.16 was released after perl 5.6.2.

A list of several years of release announcements showing the non-monotonicity of release numbers over time can be found [here](http://perlmonks.org/?node=Recent%20Perl%20Release%20Announcements).